# laravel 4 polymorphic relationships

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, polymorphism

I'm trying to get my head around using polymorphic relationships in Laravel 4, but I can't work out how to do the following:

I have a users table, customers, suppliers and partners tables and a userhistories table which has a one to many with users and morph many (called historable) with customers, suppliers and partners.

I want to get the latest 10 userhistories for the (Auth::user) logged in user that are linked to the customers table without including those for the other two tables, but I can't work out the Fluent query(s) to let me do this. Help! Thanks.

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: can you show the code

Comment: If got everything set up, and I can get what I want by explicitly setting the historable_type key to 'Customer', but obviously I want to do it 'Eloquently' by something like: 
    $user = Auth::user();
    $history = $user->historable()->orderBy('createdDate', 'desc')->with('Customer')->take(10);
to just get the latest 10 Customer related history entries. Given that the above is gibbersish, I can't work out how to chain the query starting at the User, so that it only retrieves the history entries linked to the Customer model. I'm missing something. Thanks for your help @Trying Tobemyself Rahul

Comment: you can do something like `Historable::with('Customer')->where('user_id',$user_id)->take(10);`

Comment: Historable is the name of the polymorph relationship, Userhistory is the name of the history model, but when I substitute that into you suggestion: Userhistory::with('Customer')->where('user_id',$user->id)->take(10);   it returns an Eloquent Builder object rather than the data.

Comment: what exactly it returns??

Comment: Far too long for a comment, but it starts: object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder)[841]
protected 'query' => 
object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder)[842]
protected 'connection' => 
object(Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection)[822]
protected 'pdo' => 
object(PDO)[823]
...
protected 'queryGrammar' => 
object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\MySqlGrammar)[824]
...
protected 'schemaGrammar' => null
protected 'postProcessor' => 
object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Processors\Processor)[825]
...
protected 'events' => 
object(Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher)[79]
...

Comment: paset it on paste.laravel.io

Comment: Will do. In the mean time, this works: $user = Auth::user();
$histories = $user->userhistories()->where('historable_type', 'Customer')->orderBy('whenaccessed', 'desc')->take(10); but I don't like having to set the morph type key by hand.

Comment: its at [paste.laravel.com/zG9](http://paste.laravel.com/zG9)

Comment: Forgot `->get()`, that's why it's returning a Builder object.

Comment: But anyway, if you set up your relationship correctly, `$user->userHistories()->orderBy('when_accessed', 'DESC')->take(10)->get()` should be automatically setting a where clause for the `historable_type` for you.

Comment: @Raphael_ you're quite right, get() solves that issue. However it now returns an error saying it can't find the historable collection. It looks like you can't eager load on a morph relation (makes sense I guess - multiple models in one collection).

Comment: Well, you can, of course. But if you want to add extra restrictions to it, you'll have to handle it differently. Take a look at Eager Load Constraints: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading